# Watson Assistant (Chatbot) cannot display images on its response

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, facebook-messenger-bot, watson-assistant

I tried using the dialog Image response but, my chatbot cannot display images and shows this Warning: "Cannot load image from url:"

This chatbot is Integrated in Facebook messenger.

I tried using google drive public links | Imgur | Facebook links but nothing changed.

[this is a screenshot of the warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENn2N.png)

Comment: Where have you tried the image response, in Facebook Messenger? The "try it" has limitations. Have you checked the image URI in a browser that it can be accessed? Please add this information.

Comment: I tried the Image response on both. for the "try it now" this warning just pops up. for Facebook messenger it just ignores it without displaying anything. I only   Requested: pages_messaging for the messenger app, do I need to request anything else

Comment: @data_henrik , I checked the image URI on my browser and  it can be accessed normally.

Comment: Can the image URI be accessed without any login and / or cookies? Those checks helped me to display images.

Comment: can u provide here the image uri? assuming its accessible via public network... otherwise FB won't be rendering it anyhow

Comment: I tried all these: https://imgur.com/3PKILMg | https://drive.google.com/file/d/19HTqnPTUcvLLwfK5Yvk8_kSVzLZ7RHn7/view | https://www.facebook.com/GunnerZ.eg/photos/p.155995749721733/155995749721733

Comment: I only Requested: pages_messaging for the messenger app, do I need to request anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you all for helping me.

Problem was in the "Image URL", all I needed was to open the image in a new tab then take the url.

like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMThS.jpg